# Code is broken but I cannot seem to find the mistake

Tags: python-3.7

So, basically. What happened is that I keep getting the error; IndexError: string index out of range. I am wondering what has happened?

I have tried changing the way the code was presented and tried changing IDE's but that hasn't worked.

EDIT: SOLVED. I might add for those wondering, this was supposed to be able to find +, -, * and /  in a math equation written in-console.

```py
def OpFind(cal):
    n = 0
    a = 0
    while n != "+" or n != "-" or n != "*" or n != "/":
        n = (cal[a])
        a += 1

    return n


calc = str(input())

print(OpFind(calc))
```

IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Please note that `n` will always be different from at least one of those symbols, if it is equal to `+`, then it is different from `-` and vice versa. Perhaps you meant to use `and` instead of `or` ?

Comment: What is cal[a]? What is this program supposed to do, please mention that in the question.

Comment: Instead I would restructure the loop, do a for-loop over the symbols of the string, check if it is one of those you want and then return it. If you reach the end of the for-loop, then you also need to decide what to return or do when no such operator is found in the string, something which you haven't done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has happened is that you've created a loop that will trundle through the whole string and then inside the loop you will eventually try to grab a character outside of the string and get that exception. **Always**.

This expression:

```
n != "+" or n != "-" or n != "*" or n != "/"
```

will always be true (though it's been a while since I used Python so it might be `null` or `None` if `n` is similar, I don't remember, but this doesn't apply here).

`n` will always be different to *at least* 3 of those symbols. For instance, if `n` is `"+"`, then it will be different from `"-"`, `"*"` and `"/"`.

Let me rephrase that. The only way your expression would allow the loop to break is if you find a symbol that is identical to all those different strings **at the same time**. This is not possible, hence why it will go through the whole string regardless of content.

I am guessing you meant to use `and` instead of `or`.

However, what I would do would be to rewrite your code so that it will end when the string ends, because you have another case you haven't covered, what if the string contains none of them? It will always crash with an exception then.

Instead, do this:

```
def OpFind(cal):
    for n in cal:
        if n == "+" or n == "-" or n == "*" or n == "/":
            return n
    return None
```

This will not fall of the end of string, and it will return `None` if you gave it a string not containing any of the operators.

There are also various ways to make the code even more succinct, like using the `in` keyword:

```
def OpFind(cal):
    for n in cal:
        if n in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
            return n
    return None
```

There's also built-in functions that may help, like `next`:

```
def OpFind(cal):
    return next((n for n in cal if n in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]), None)
```